# Exception in Spring Boot while connecting to AWS Elastic Cache in Cluster Mode with SSL

Tags: spring-data-redis

We are using  **spring-boot-starter-data-redis (1.5.9.RELEASE)** to connect to AWS Elastic Cache ( Redis) in cluster mode.

Everything is working fine if we not enable Redis Auth (password) and encrypt data in transit in AWS Elastic Cache.

We are getting connection reset exception when data in transit and redis auth enabled.

```
configured with below environment variables.

spring.redis.cluster.nodes=node1**.com:6379,node2***.com:6379

spring.redis.ssl=true

spring.redis.password=******
```

Exception Below :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.config.internalCacheAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cache/annotation/ProxyCachingConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.interceptor.BeanFactoryCacheOperationSourceAdvisor]: Factory method 'cacheAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheAutoConfigurationValidator': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/RedisCacheConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cacheManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/RedisAutoConfiguration$RedisConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redisTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/RedisAutoConfiguration$RedisConnectionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:346)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
```

---

More Exception Details :

```
caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:202)
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:40)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:151)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:215)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:340)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:239)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:96)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:126)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:117)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.auth(BinaryClient.java:564)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.auth(BinaryJedis.java:2138)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterConnectionHandler.initializeSlotsCache(JedisClusterConnectionHandler.java:36)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterConnectionHandler.<init>(JedisClusterConnectionHandler.java:17)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.<init>(JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.java:24)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedisCluster.<init>(BinaryJedisCluster.java:54)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster.<init>(JedisCluster.java:93)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.createCluster(JedisConnectionFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.createCluster(JedisConnectionFactory.java:280)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet(JedisConnectionFactory.java:241)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define at least one redis template for connection. Something like this (depends on your client)

```
@Bean
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    return new JedisConnectionFactory();
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    return template;
}
```

Comment: Spring Boot does auto configure and it is working for me if SSL is not enabled in the cluster. I am looking for some help in fixing the issue when SSL enabled.

Comment: still looking for answer to this question.

Comment: @Ram Did you figure out a solution to this issue? I am also running into same issue.